# FT232RL Chip is not working (USB to TTL)

Tags: usb, uart, serial, ttl, ft232

I used an FT232RL chip to make a USB to TTL converter using the schematic below.
Although I can send a message and the TX LED is lightining up, I cannot receive any messages.
Can anyone see a problem with my schematic?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. "I can make serial communication but I cannot receive any message." What do you mean "make serial communication" then?

Comment: Connect TX and RX of the IC (loopback). If you send something in the terminal, you must immediately receive the same symbol back. It's the most basic loopback test for UART bridges.

Comment: Does your host see the device on its USB port? What are you connecting USBTX and USBRX to?

Comment: Put an oscilloscope on the RX line. The chip has to work for the windows drivers to load properly.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I can open connection via Hercules program. But I cannot receive any messages. I connected USBTX pin to RX pin of my ESP32 board and vice versa

Comment: @Ilya thanks for the suggestion i made a mistake when drawing the PCB i found the error. Its from another part of my board

Comment: `I cannot receive any messages` ... receive where? ... what is sending the messages?